# "eclipse" is loading dependency into classpath even if this dependency is exclude in pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

Let's assume that I have such structure project:
Module A
-> Dependency FOO
Module B (the parent of B is A)
-> Exclude dependency FOO

Even if I exclude dependency FOO from module B eclipse (neon.3) still is loading FOO dependency into classpath. Any ideas what is the reason for such behave?

Answer (score 0):

if Your are using dependency type is war, so there is no resolution happening into this. Maven overlays war contents over your project. the artifact will contains dependent library in to `WEB-INF/lib` folder, 
When war is published to repository. During the overlay, it doesn't treat lib directory any different from any static resource unless you dose not tell it to exclude in different way you can refer below link for 'overlay'.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html

you can also use `<configuration>` :

```
<configuration>
    <excludeGroupIds>org.apache.hadoop,org.apache.hbase</excludeGroupIds>
</configuration>
```